# What is the EJB Client?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

ALL, I am a newbie for EJB of Java World, After reading the good book named [Ejb3.0 in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988347), I have a question about Session Bean. What is the EJB Client for a session bean? Say we have some code looks like below.

```
//EJB definition
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface PlaceOrder {
  ..
  void addItem(Long itemId);
  Long confirmOrder(); 
  ..
}

@Stateful
public class PlaceOrderBean implements PlaceOrder {
  private List<Long> items;
  public PlaceOrderBean () {
    items = new ArrayList<Long>();
  }

  public void addItem(Long itemId) {
    items.add(itemId);
  }

  @Remove
  public Long confirmOrder() {
    Order order = new Order();
    ...
    return order.getOrderId();
  }
}


//Client 
import javax.ejb.EJB;
public class PlaceOrderTestClient {
  @EJB
  private static PlaceOrder placeOrder1;
  @EJB
  private static PlaceOrder placeOrder2;
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Exercising PlaceOrder EJB...");
    placeOrder1.addItem(new Long(200));
    placeOrder1.addItem(new Long(201));

    Long orderId = placeOrder1.confirmOrder();
    System.out.println("Order confirmation number: " + orderId);
  }
}
```

**Updated**

The EJB Client means `placeOrder1` and `placeOrder2` or the main application ? Does it means multiple EJB clients? Another question is what if it is in `Servlet` instead of main method ? thanks.

Comment: Correction please, the non static variable _placeOrder1_ cannot be called directly in to the main method.i.e. **non static variables or methods cannot be referred from a static context**.

Comment: @Visruth CV ,thanks. alread done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EJBClient` is a local program which can call and operate `Remote` Bean

Here, in your scenario whatever triggers the `PlaceOrderBean` is a client

InCase of Servlet, if `Servlet` calls the `EJB` it is technically client but often called `Facade`

Comment: Hi, @TechExchange , Please review the updated content again, How many clients in this scenario? thanks.

Comment: no `placeOrder1` and `2` are instance/reference of PlaceOrderBean . code using it becomes the client

Comment: Forgive my poor understanding , I am not sure what you mean. the word `using` means calling the method of the EJB not just declaring the reference of EJB type?  So, In my opinion, there is only one EJB client in this example, although I declare 2 references of EJB type.please correct me if I was wrong. thanks.

Comment: I mean the only one EJB client is the reference of `placeOrder1`, not the `placeOrder2`. Because I didn't use the `placeOrder2`, thanks.

Comment: I've been wondering about this question myself. This answer makes it a little bit clearer but not quite. What is meant by "triggers" in "whatever triggers the PlaceOrderBean is a client". Is it the `PlaceOrderTestClient` class that trigger the beans?

Answer (score 0):

A EJB Client is local program to execute the functionality/behavior implemented at server side.

Here *PlaceOrderTestClient* is EJB Client.